# Extract season and episode from .vob file name to .nfo

Tags: bash

I've been working on my first Bash script which generates `.nfo` files using the corresponding file names in a given directory. Using code I've found elsewhere, I've been able to achieve this and also include the following text within each `.nfo` file:

```
<episodedetails>
<title>This is working successfully</title>
<episode>This bit however is not working</episode>
<season>This bit however is not working</season>
</episodedetails>
```

What I'm struggling with is the Episode and Season fields within the `nfo` file.

My file name format is like this:
**Holy Bible - The Book of Ephesians (2009) - S01E01 (Introduction, Background, God's Blueprint).vob**

The output of that particular `nfo` file (at present) is:

```
<episodedetails>
<title>Introduction, Background, God's Blueprint</title>
<episode>2009)</episode>
<season>The Book of Ephesians (2009)</season>
</episodedetails>
```

Please could you help me tweak my code so that the `nfo` reads:

```
<episodedetails>
<title>Introduction, Background, God's Blueprint</title>
<episode>01</episode>
<season>01</season>
</episodedetails>
```

The specific area of code that's going wrong is as follows:

```
episode="${filename#* - *(}"
episode="${episode% - *.vob}"

season="${filename#* - }"
season="${season% - *.vob}"
```

The code in its entirety:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -rd '' file; do

filename="${file##*/}"

title="${filename%\).vob}"
title="${title##* (}"

episode="${filename#* - *(}"
episode="${episode% - *.vob}"

season="${filename#* - }"
season="${season% - *.vob}"

cat > "${file%\.vob}.nfo" <<< \
"<episodedetails>
<title>${title}</title>
<episode>${episode}</episode>
<season>${season}</season>
</episodedetails>"

done < <(find . -name '*.vob' -print0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bash` has a nice `=~` operator of the `[[ ... ]]` conditional expressions that is handy in such cases. It tries to match a string (your file name) with a regular expression, and supports capture groups. The captured matches are available in the `BASH_REMATCH` indexed array. Example of use in your case:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
  [[ "$file" =~ ^.*-\ S([0-9]+)E([0-9]+)\ \((.*)\)\.vob$ ]] &&
  cat > "${file%\.vob}.nfo" <<< \
"<episodedetails>
<title>${BASH_REMATCH[3]}</title>
<episode>${BASH_REMATCH[2]}</episode>
<season>${BASH_REMATCH[1]}</season>
</episodedetails>"
done < <(find . -name '*.vob' -print0)
```

Comment: I meant to add a regex variant to my answer but now I don't have to. This is nice in that it extends to fewer or additional digits, and is easy to extend to accept optional whitespace around S and E.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, it is nice. Also because it easily allows to test if the string matches the regexp, and, in this example, skip non-matching files if any.

Comment: (The here string is still crazy.)

Comment: Agreed, I would have used a `printf`. But I usually try to keep as much as possible of the original code so as to focus on the primary issue and avoid distraction.

Answer (score 2):

With only a single example, it's hard to know what will work in the general case. But I would focus on the very specific formatting of the S##E## token.

```
temp=${filename%*S[0-9][0-9]E[0-9][0-9]*}
sxxexx=${filename#"$temp"}
season=${sxxexx%E[0-9][0-9]*}
season=${season#S}
episode=${sxxexx#S"$season"E}
episode=${episode%%\ *}
```

The use of [parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to get the work done is slightly cumbersome, but being able to avoid invoking external processes should keep it pretty fast.

As an aside, your use of a here string looks weird. The formatting would probably make more sense as a regular here document. The `-` after `<<` allows you to indent with tabs (but not with spaces; unfortunately, Stack Overflow renders tabs as spaces, so you won't be able to directly copy/paste this).

```
cat > "${file%\.vob}.nfo" <<-____
    <episodedetails>
    <title>${title}</title>
    <episode>${episode}</episode>
    <season>${season}</season>
    </episodedetails>
____
```

In general, you want to indent each block inside a `while`, `until`, `for`, `case` etc to help human readers see the structure of your code.

Comment: Many thanks. Unless I implemented incorrectly, that has generated the NFO's with no value against the episode or series fields.

Comment: Thanks for the additional test cases; updated now with a properly tested version. Ridiculously, I had lowercase S and E in the original answer, and one of the parameter expansions was the wrong way around.